# Populate Ngform with javascript from xml file

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, forms

**Problem:** I'm trying to populate a form with a xml file uploaded by the user. So I have a modal window where the user inserts the file and then it returns to the form component. In the form component it sends the file to the javascript file tha's going to parse the file. After that I a mapped the xml file and got all the values from the file and assigned them to corresponding key of the form object. Now I don't know hot to populate the actual html form with that object and I don't know how to bring it to the typescript.

**Part of the Angular form:**

```
<form #f="ngForm" [ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}" class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
    <!----------------- LOCAL ------------------->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm mb-2">
            <h4>Local</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="data">Data</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="data" placeholder="Data" ngModel #date="ngModel">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="time">Hora</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="time" placeholder="time" ngModel #time="ngModel">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="sala">Sala</label>
                <select id="sala" name="sala" class="form-control form-control-sm" ngModel #sala="ngModel">
                    <option disabled>Escolher Sala</option>
                    <option value="1">Sala Suggia</option>
                    <option value="2">Sala 2</option> 
                    <option value="3">Sala de Ensaio 1</option> 
                    <option value="4">Sala de Ensaio 2</option> 
                    <option value="5">Cibermúsica</option> 
                    <option value="6">Restaurante</option> 
                    <option value="7">Sala VIP</option> 
                    <option value="8">Terraço VIP</option> 
                    <option value="9">Sala Renascença</option> 
                    <option value="10">Foyer Nascente</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="edificio">Edíficio</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="edificio" placeholder="Edíficio" ngModel #building="ngModel">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cidade">Cidade</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="cidade" placeholder="Cidade" ngModel #city="ngModel">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pais">País</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="pais" placeholder="País" ngModel #country="ngModel">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Typescript:** In here I open the modal window, where I insert the xml file and when closed, I bring with my the file. So I can use it in the form component.

```
read(f: NgForm) {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(XmlComponent, {size:"lg", backdrop: 'static'});
    modalRef.componentInstance.title = 'xml';
    modalRef.result.then((result) => {
      if (result) {
      this.name = result.name; 
      this.isActive = true;
      this.file = result;
      this.names.push(this.name);
      this.xml = changeFile(this.file, f["form"]["value"]);  
      }
    });  
  }
```

**Javascript:** In this file I read the xml file, parse it and then get the values from the file.
After that I try to populate the form object with the corresponding values.

```
var form;

function readFile(event) {
  "use strict"; 
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(event.target.result, 'text/xml');
  populateData(form, xmlDoc);
}

function changeFile(file, form1) {
  "use strict";
  form = form1;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', readFile);
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

function populateData(form, xmlDom){ 
  "use strict";
  var root = xmlDom.documentElement;
  var metadataNodes = root.querySelectorAll('entry');
  var map = {};
  metadataNodes.forEach(function(metadata) {
    var key = metadata.querySelector('key').textContent;
    var value = metadata.querySelector('value').textContent;
    map[key] = value;
  });
  //populate form here
  Object.keys(form).forEach(e => console.log(`key=${e}  value=${map[e]}`));    

}
```